# PHP Mysqli fetch_assoc() on joined queries

Tags: php, mysqli

Whenever I run this piece of code I get only the values from `test2` due to the columns being the same.

```
$Return = array();
$Output = $MySQLi->query("SELECT * FROM test1 as A LEFT JOIN test2 as B ON A.abc=B.abc");
while($Row = $Output->fetch_assoc()) {
    $Return[] = $Row;
}
var_dump($Return);
```

This is what I get.

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["abc"]=> string(1) "2" [123]=> string(1) "3" } }
```

Is there a way to make fetch_assoc() return something like this?

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["A.abc"]=> string(1) "7" [A.123]=> string(1) "8"  ["B.abc"]=> string(1) "2" [B.123]=> string(1) "3" } }
```

Comment: You need to create alias of each column of table test1 and test2

Comment: @Saty is there any way to avoid this? because the actual tables I am working with are not small and in some cases I join 4 at a time.

Comment: Use "SELECT A.*,B.* FROM test1 as A LEFT JOIN test2 as B ON A.abc=B.abc"

Comment: @RuchishParikh That gives me the same result

Comment: not same result it will give you ['A']['abc'] and ['B']['abc']

Comment: @RuchishParikh I am running this and getting `array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["abc"]=> string(1) "2" [123]=> string(1) "3" } }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use alias while selecting the data and best is select only which is needed instead of using *

Write your query as below:-

```
 SELECT A.abc as 'A.abc',A.123 as 'A.123',B.abc as 'B.abc',B.123 as 'B.123'  
 FROM test1 as A 
 LEFT JOIN test2 as B 
 ON A.abc=B.abc
```

Comment: Is there anyway that I could make the column names start with their corresponding table alias? without defining all columns?

Comment: You need to define columns names which you want to differentiate.  You can also write  "SELECT A.*,B.abc as 'B.abc',B.123 as 'B.123'  
 FROM test1 as A 
 LEFT JOIN test2 as B 
 ON A.abc=B.abc"

Answer (score -1):

Although in general the answer to this question is to define aliases in your query, to solve this particular inconvenience (along with infinite number of real problems), you have to make all the similar data into a single table. This is the only proper way.